# How to handle global resources in spring cloud dataflow?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I'm learning the concepts of spring cloud dataflow and wondering what is the common way of storing global resources.

For example, when I have a stream with a [pmml-processor](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/pmml/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-processor-pmml/README.adoc) and I would like to retrain the underlying pmml-model periodically via a spring-cloud-task.

Where would I store the model, so that it can be used as a (read-only)-resource by the processor and updated by the task every night? Is there a concept of a global storage in spring cloud dataflow? 
Should I just use a traditional database outside of the spring-cloud or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no general concept of shared storage within Spring Cloud Data Flow itself, but the Spring `Resource` used to provide the model for the PMML processor is pretty flexible (see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html and in particular Table 8.1 for a few path options that can be used for the `pmml.model-location` parameter). So there are a couple options out of the box:

- use a shared filesystem (which could be then accessed via the `file://` protocol);
- store the model in a location accessible that can be served as a static resource via HTTP;

Additional options (which require including additional jars in the application) are available for S3 (via https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/) and HDFS (via Spring for Apache Hadoop - see http://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-hdfs-resource-loader).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I ended up using this to fix it

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#resources-resourceloader

```
groovy-transform --script=file:///root/apps/script.groovy
```

Thanks Marius Bogoevici.